# Show only first n cases in a caselist?

Tags: commcare

I have a workflow that would be improved by restricting displayed cases to the first n returned cases on a caselist.

Is this possible?

Notes:

- There could be up to 1,500 cases on a mobile device
- Sorting is randomized (and re-randomized) regularly based on events in a separate module. It's a pretty loose algorithm for assigning the random numbers with possible duplicates. It uses MOD, which I think means they'll always be ints.

Comment: What are the characteristics of the case property that it is sorted on? Is it a decimal from 1 to 0 or is it a range of numbers where 1 is top and N is the bottom? If it's from 1 to N you could easily restrict the case list by adding a filtering ensure that the sort property is less then say 15 to show the top 15 cases.

Comment: @BenRudolph I've accepted your edits and (I hope) provided some clarity about the sorting

Answer (score 3):

This can be accomplished by adding a filter based on the `position()` of the current element, but the syntax will be a bit of a hack because you need to introduce a second predicate filter after the current one to constrain the scope.

Example:
If your current filter is

`property < 50`

I believe you can replace it with

`property < 50][position() < N`

where `N` is the number of results you want.

NOTE: You won't be able to see "more" cases, so the user will have go to back and forth in order to see additional results.

Update: It looks like HQ no longer allows you to use `][` to introduce a second predicate filter expression, so this doesn't work at the moment.

Comment: Nice I was searching for a function like this here https://confluence.dimagi.com/display/commcarepublic/CommCare+Functions

Comment: @ClaytonSims I think maybe position() doesn't return exactly what one would expect. I say this because the original result was 10+ cases and applying position()<5 got me only 1 result.

Comment: Important note: this solution will give the first N-1 returned cases, but unfortunately it identifies those cases BEFORE the sorting happens.  So in my situation, 9 cases make it through the filter then it gives me the first 5 and THEN it randomizes them, instead of giving me 9 cases, randomizing the order and giving me back the resulting "first 5."